# If my max cog is 50t and I got a 52t cog

Tags: derailleur, cassette, sprocket

Hello I just bought a ltwoo groupset on ebay because I want to go cheap for my first ride since I'm not sure if I will be riding a lot. I went on the ltwoo website later on and found on that their max cog for their rear derailleur is 50t and I got a 52t will that make any difference?

Comment: Are you referring to a rear derailleur or a front derailleur?  52T is enormous for a cassette's lowest gear, but not impossible.

Comment: @Criggie SRAM released their 10-52t 12s cassette (I suppose to outdo Shimano’s 10-51) and a bunch of overseas companies followed suit.

Comment: rear derailluer

Answer (score 1):

It’s a 4% increase in diameter. I reckon you’ll be fine. The genuine SRAM systems may be more sensitive, but this one will be just fine.

Comment: Second that. If your derailleur can take 50 cogs, it should be OK with 52. OEM may disagree. But try it and see.